# Issue with Chrome and text field character limits

Tags: google-chrome

Attempting to submit content in a text field in Chrome, this is a web based tool I utilize at work.

In IE it works fine, but when I attempt to submit a query into the space it returns this error.

> Please shorten this text to 1950 characters or less (you are currently
>   using 1999 characters)

I this is an issue with the HTML working correctly with Chrome or is there a setting in Chrome to tell it not to do the check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome handles the MaxLength property of TextAreas differently; specifically it likes to count two characters for each new line instead of just one (`\r\n` vs. just `\n`).

This is a common problem:

> Uneditable Text Fields and Browser Compatibility
>
> Occasionally, when an uneditable field selected from a drop-down menu
>   or a search box is very long - for example, a course title - you may
>   receive this error message:
>
> **"Please shorten this field to X characters or less. (You are currently
>   using X.)"**
>
> This error message is directly related to the way in which some
>   browsers interpret our application pages. In order to proceed with
>   your application, please *use either Internet Explorer or Mozilla
>   Firefox*.

[Source](https://embarksupport.zendesk.com/entries/20225052-Error-Message-Please-shorten-this-text-)

See these StackOverflow Questions:

- [Chrome counts characters wrong in textarea with maxlength attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030921/chrome-counts-characters-wrong-in-textarea-with-maxlength-attribute)
- [Different maxlength validation of textarea with newlines in Chrome and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016511/different-maxlength-validation-of-textarea-with-newlines-in-chrome-and-firefox)

To "Fix it", so that Chrome behaves the same way other browsers do, the web app will need to be modified.